# Possible bug with angular select using typed value in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, select, angularjs

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NFQFp/

HTML:

```
<body ng-app ng-controller="bodyCtrl">
<input autofocus="autofocus" ng-model="fname"/>
<select ng-model="state">
<option ng-repeat="st in states" value="{{st}}" ng-selected="state == st">{{st}}</option>
</select>
{{state}}
</body>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function bodyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.state = '';
    $scope.states =["AK","AL","AR","AS","AZ","CA","CO","CT","DC","DE","FL","GA","GU","HI","IA","ID","IL","IN","KS","KY","LA","MA","MD","ME","MH","MI","MN","MO","MS","MT","NC","ND","NE","NH","NJ","NM","NV","NY","OH","OK","OR","PA","PR","PW","RI","SC","SD","TN","TX","UT","VA","VI","VT","WA","WI","WV","WY"]
}
```

If you tab into the select box and type A then L, the model remains with AK as its value.  If you type A then R or A then Z, it works fine.  Not sure what is happening here.  Seems to be the second of any result set doesn't update the model. AL, CO, DE... etc dont work as expected.  This only seems to be a problem when typing, selecting the item from the list updates the model as expected.  If you select AL, then AK, then type AL, it will update fine.  Could this have something to do with an event not firing from the browser?  I am using Chrome, which seems to update the model as you type, unlike firefox which doesn't update it until you blur the select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `ng-repeat` with select; use:

```
<select ng-model="state" ng-options="st for st in states">
```

See [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aselect).

Now pressing A L goes to AL (you have to press them quickly enough). Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XyaR9/

Comment: That fiddle still seems to have the same problem for me

Comment: Also, the issue was not that it didn't select the right one in the select box, the issue is that it does't update the model property

Comment: The model gets updated when you leave the select in both cases... I think this is normal. The same behaviour occurs when, with the select focused, you press up/down. Still, you should use `ng-options`.

Comment: I agree ng-options is the way to go, but I tried typing AL, which highlights AL in the select but doesn't change the model.  Then clicking out of the select, still doesn't update it

Comment: Seems firefox updates when you blur the select, but Chrome does not

Comment: Indeed, it is as you say; I am sorry I don't know what more to do. Looks like browser bug? IE 10 seems to update the model immediately, even with the up/down buttons. So this behaviour is inconsistent across browsers and probably cannot be relied upon. Better look for a workaround...

Comment: @badaboum my workaround was to set the tab index of the select to a negative number so users cannot tab into it easily.  For me it seemed tabbing into the field was the cause of all the issues.

Comment: Was a solution ever found to this issue? I came across the same problem. Here's my SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27447247/angular-select-not-changing-model-value-when-tabbing-through-input-fields-in-chr